# element positioning float and changing window size

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-float

I have made a simple website and am happy witht he fact that I have had minimal use of div elements. I cannot explain why I do not like using divs, I just dont. That being said I have 2 elements side by side and when the browser shrinks the elements collapse one under the other (it's a paragraph with an image next to it, for ease of picturing).

Other than using position relative and adjusting pixels or wrapping the elements in divs is there a way to prevent two floated elements from changing position when the browser screen shrinks?

Answer (score 1):

you could have a min-width on the container of those two elements. and if they aren't in a div, remember that `<body>` can also have this min-width

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a width on the container for exampleboth the elements for example say
 < class="element-container"> in order to seperate both the elements overlaying on each other.